# How do I obtain the row index of a row in rich:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to output the row index for each row in a `rich:dataTable`. It looks like the `stateVar` attribute would do this, but I can't figure out how to use it.

The reference documentation for this is hopeless:

> The attribute provides access to a component state on the client side

Simply outputting the state variable yields "org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor$1@f63387". I had a quick look around the web for the source, but had no luck.

Does anyone know which property of the `dataTable` will give me the row index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `rowKeyVar` attribute.